# Instant logging and file generation in Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am currently using Community version on linux server, have configured db2audit process
Which generated audit files at respective location. Then user have to manually execute db2audit archive command to achieved logs file and have to execute thedb2 extract command to extract the archived files into flat ascIII files and then we have to load the files into respective tables.
There only we can analyze the logs by query the tables. In this whole process lots of manual intervention is required.

Question:-Do we have any config settings or utility
with the help of which we can generate logs files which include SQL statement event, host, session id,Timestamp and all instantly and automatically.
need to set instant level logging mechanism to generate flat files for logs of any SQL execution happened or any event triggered in database level in DB2 on linux server

Comment: Auditing is done after the fact. Are looking for security monitoring?

Comment: hi henrik, We are looking for database event monitoring type , to capture all the SQL statements and events on database .

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to automate all the steps you mentioned with some scripts.

Comment: You may want to consider 3rd party DAM tools for this.